# scipy.optimize.curve_fit raises a runtime error

Tags: python, scipy, least-squares

This is the first time I'm using curve_fit and I haven't found examples that would match my problem. My question is, am I using curve_fit correctly data-format-wise ? If yes then my problem is mathematical and I'll have to correct it (I haven't found any mistakes yet...).
Here's my code :

```
import numpy as np
import math as m
import scipy.optimize as sci

def f4(X,Tx,Ty,Tz,i,j,k):
    res=[]
#X looks like [x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2....]
    for n in range(np.shape(X)[0]/3):
        xr=X[n*3]+Tx+m.cos(j)*m.cos(k)*X[n*3]-m.cos(j)*m.sin(k)*X[n*3+1]+m.sin(j)*X[n*3+2]
        yr=X[n*3+1]+Ty+(m.sin(i)*m.sin(j)*m.cos(k)+m.cos(i)*m.sin(k))*X[n*3]+(-m.sin(i)*m.sin(j)*m.sin(k)+m.cos(i)*m.cos(k))*X[n*3+1]-m.sin(i)*m.cos(j)*X[n*3+2]
        zr=X[n*3+2]+Tz+(-m.cos(i)*m.sin(j)*m.cos(k)+m.sin(i)*m.sin(k))*X[n*3]+(m.cos(i)*m.sin(j)*m.sin(k)+m.sin(i)*m.cos(k))*X[n*3+1]+m.cos(i)*m.cos(j)*X[n*3+2]
        res.append(xr)
        res.append(yr)
        res.append(zr)
    return res

xdata2=[998.362,5000.052,99.4,997.862,5000.052,99.4,998.362,5000.052,98.9,997.862,5000.052,98.9]
ydata2=[999.46555,4999.801,99.4,999.112,5000.15455,99.4,999.46555,4999.801,98.9,999.112,5000.15455,98.9]
p0=[1,0,0,0,0,0.8]

popt,pcov=sci.curve_fit(f4,xdata2,ydata2,p0)
```

it raises : RuntimeError: Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 1400.

According to my calculation, p0 is pretty close to the solution.
Is my code okay or should I keep looking for a mathematical mistake ?

if anybody's curious I'm trying to find the 3 translations and the 3 rotations I must apply to a set of points Xp in order to obtain a set of points Xr.

Any piece of advice is appreciated

Edit 1/04 :

I tried unutbu's way I changed my function :

```
def f2(X,Tx,Ty,Tz,i,j,k):
    res=[]
    for n in range(np.shape(X)[0]):
        xr=X[n][0]+Tx+m.cos(j)*m.cos(k)*X[n][0]-m.cos(j)*m.sin(k)*X[n][1]+m.sin(j)*X[n][2]
    yr=X[n][1]+Ty+(m.sin(i)*m.sin(j)*m.cos(k)+m.cos(i)*m.sin(k))*X[n][0]+(-m.sin(i)*m.sin(j)*m.sin(k)+m.cos(i)*m.cos(k))*X[n][1]-m.sin(i)*m.cos(j)*X[n][2]
    zr=X[n][2]+Tz+(-m.cos(i)*m.sin(j)*m.cos(k)+m.sin(i)*m.sin(k))*X[n][0]+(m.cos(i)*m.sin(j)*m.sin(k)+m.sin(i)*m.cos(k))*X[n][1]+m.cos(i)*m.cos(j)*X[n][2]
    aux=[xr,yr,zr]
    res.append(aux)
res=np.array(res)
return res
```

I added two points to my arrays :

```
xdata3=np.array([[998.362,5000.052,99.4],[997.862,5000.052,99.4],[998.362,5000.052,98.9],[997.862,5000.052,98.9],[999.112,4999.801,98.9],[999.112,4999.801,99.4]])
ydata3=np.array([[999.46555,4999.801,99.4],[999.112,5000.15455,99.4],[999.46555,4999.801,98.9],[999.112,5000.15455,98.9],[1000.112,4999.801,98.9],[1000.112,4999.801,99.4]])
```

I tried out the function :

```
test=f2(xdata3,1,0.00001,0.00001,0.00001,0.00001,0.8)

In [17]:test
Out[17]:
array([[-1891.88925911,  9199.80185261,   198.87092002],
   [-1892.73761247,  9199.44317456,   198.87091992],
   [-1891.88926411,  9199.80185761,   197.87092002],
   [-1892.73761747,  9199.44317956,   197.87091992],
   [-1890.4366777 ,  9199.91400129,   197.87091663],
   [-1890.4366727 ,  9199.91399629,   198.87091663]])
```

Changed p0 too:

```
p0=[1,0.00001,0.00001,0.00001,0.00001,0.8]
```

Then i tried the curve_fit :

```
test=f2(xdata3,1,0.00001,0.00001,0.00001,0.00001,0.8)
```

And I've got a different error :

```
error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.
```

Not sure what happened since my test variable seems fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies solely in your choice of model function.
The data simply doesn't fit that model.

If you want to fit the data using a translation and a rotation, perhaps what you
are looking for is more like `f4` (below), which

- finds the centroid of the object, `Xbar`.
  `X-Xbar` moves the object back to a position closer to the origin.
- rotates `X-Xbar` about the origin (using `np.dot(R, X-Xbar)`), and then
- translates by `T + Xbar`.

(Note that, unlike the original
`f4`, it does not also translate by `X`.)

---

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as optimize
from math import cos, sin

def f4(X,Tx,Ty,Tz,i,j,k):
    T = np.array([Tx, Ty, Tz])[:, np.newaxis]
    X = X.reshape(-1,3).T
    Xbar = X.mean(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
    X = X - Xbar
    R = np.array([
        (cos(j)*cos(k), -cos(j)*sin(k), sin(j)),

        (sin(i)*sin(j)*cos(k)+cos(i)*sin(k), 
         -sin(i)*sin(j)*sin(k)+cos(i)*cos(k), 
         -sin(i)*cos(j)),

        (-cos(i)*sin(j)*cos(k)+sin(i)*sin(k), 
         cos(i)*sin(j)*sin(k)+sin(i)*cos(k), 
         cos(i)*cos(j))])
    result = np.dot(R, X) + T + Xbar
    return result.T.ravel()

p0=[1,0,0,0,0,0.8]

xdata2 = np.array([998.362,5000.052,99.4,997.862,5000.052,99.4,998.362,5000.052,98.9,997.862,5000.052,98.9])
ydata2 = [999.46555,4999.801,99.4,999.112,5000.15455,99.4,999.46555,4999.801,98.9,999.112,5000.15455,98.9]

popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(f4, xdata2, ydata2, p0)
print(popt)
```

yields

```
[  1.17677500e+00  -7.42250000e-02  -4.02305065e-37  -1.28557241e-20
  -1.61334110e-20  -7.85398164e-01]
```

Comment: I don't really understand how I haven't enough data. I'm looking for 3 translation and 3 rotations, which is 6 parameters. I've got 4 points so 12 values.

I managed to make it work for small angles in a linear least squares procedure : I approximate cos(angle) by 1 and sin(angle) by angle. It gives me a linear system. That is how I use it usually since what I'm used to do is find transformation between geodesic system, and angles in those transformations are very small.

Comment: Yep it works great ! Thanks a lot. It doesnt give me what I expected but I'll check that out, my math is probably a bit rusty.

Comment: Sorry if my math is awfull but is this a problem if it does not translate by X in the result given by f4 ? Because the equation is Y=X+T+R*X. If it is not important, How can I find the coordinates of the point (x,y,z) after the transformation. Is it T+R*X ?
I tried adding X as a translation but I got the RuntimeError

Comment: I just tried comparing ydata to the result of R*xdata+T : the difference on 2 points is around 40cm, and on the 2 other it's 20cm (my data describe a face of a cube paralel to the x axis before translation and rotation). Pretty odd

Comment: Are you using `X = X.reshape(-1,3).T`? An earlier version of my post had `X = X.reshape(3, -1)`, which is wrong...

Comment: Awesome ! I'm around 2mm of difference on every point. Thank you very much. I did not understand it all but I can now take time to review how this works. Thanks again !

Comment: If you have questions about my implementation, feel free to ask.

Comment: As a matter of fact I do. The purpose of this least square treatment is to place an 3D object precisely in a software Revit. The problem is when I use the parameters in popt it does not quite suit me. If I apply just the rotation, the object seems to be at the right angle. But the translation parameters are huge compared to what I need to apply, translation in X axis should be around 1m, the others 0. I don't really know how I am supposed to do this.

Comment: I just found out by measurement that the translation is supposed to be 0.58155 on X axis. Others 0.

Comment: Your initial X is very far from the origin. A small rotation about the origin moves the point a long distance. Remember that the rotation happens before the translation: `np.dot(R, X)` first, then `T` is added. This is why the `T` is large. The translation `T` can not be applied to `X` before the rotation.

Comment: Given `popt` and a 3-component vector `X`, you could compute `f4(X, *popt)-X`. This gives the amount by which `X` is ultimately translated (according to the model and best-fit parameters `popt`). Or, given `xdata2`, compute `(f4(xdata2, *popt) - xdata2).reshape(-1,3).mean(axis=0)` to get the *average* amount the model says each point in the 3D object should be translated.

Comment: When I calculate f4(X,*popt)-X it gives me the translation that I would use on each specific point, not the translation of the object which is no good for me. In my software the object doesn't move very much with just the rotation ( few centimeters) so I guess my problem is that I the axis that I defined in the API musn't be the origin axis. They must be some kind of view axis. I'll explore that, Thanks a lot !

Comment: I modified the code to subtract the centroid from `X` before applying the rotation. This results in the `T`-values in `popt` being smaller. I know it is not as small as the value you are expecting, but that is what `curve_fit` finds to be the best fit parameters given the data and model function.

Comment: Just tried it, didn't give me what I need. Eventually I think that the code without the substraction of X suits me better. It's really a software problem now because I'm pretty close to having what I need, I just can't manage to apply it to the origin of my project. I'll find my way around it eventually. Thanks a lot

Comment: I tried applying it to a particular point which I thought could be the origin by substrating to all my coordinates in xdata and ydata the coordinates of this point. It almost worked as all parameters are fine exept the Y translation which is -1.394. When I set that to 0 it is exactly what I need. Weird... I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 0):

For some of these fitting routines, you should *not* start the initial parameters at 0.0. Might want to try to set those to be something small but non zero (1e-6).